# xCode visual memory debugger stand alone object

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, memory-management

Ok, I'm trying to debug the fact that some of my objects are not being deallocated when my user logs out. I love the visual memory debugging tool in xCode so I used it.

First, it flags a memory leak on an object that I know should be deallocated:

[image]

So I click it and see this:

[image]

Weird! No (visual) references to it.

I then click on the call stack to the right and simply get taken to the place I constructed the object in the first place:

[image]

I don't understand why this is staying in memory.

Comment: Try putting a breakpoint where you expect it to be deallocated.

Comment: I stumbled across weird situations with the memory graph (e.g. situations where an object appeared in the left panel but actually was apparently deallocated). Yours is a little different because not only does it show up in the panel, but you've got the warning icon, too. I'd suggest going old-school and diving into the Allocations tool in Instruments and looking at where the strong references were established and released. Or maybe you can see if you can prune out unrelated stuff and share a [simple example that manifests the problem you describe](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).